# Rate limit a public API endpoint in Kong

Tags: api, kong

We currently use Kong as an API gateway with all endpoints requiring authentication.

We need to build a public facing web app that retrieves information from a service and we want to use the Kong API gateway and other technologies that are familiar to us.

Some of the options we are considering are:

1. Use api key authentication having the api key exposed via the internet on the public website (this will at least allow us to rate limit as we are likely to have a multiple consumers of this service)
2. Use anonymous authentication on the endpoint
3. Build another web app and use it as a proxy to kong with basic authentication between the two (i.e user -> web app -> kong -> internal api, rather than user -> kong -> internal app)

I wanted some feedback or suggestions on what way we should go.

Comment: Quite strange to put a proxy between user and kong as kong is already a proxy.
What is your issue or what are you trying to solve ?

Comment: When we setup kong initially it wasn’t ment to be external facing. We now need a public facing API that will be consumed by a SPA embedded in a public website.

Comment: What about rate limiting the public endpoint by ip and not using any authentication. You can set public and private route on the same kong